# How to make a script run onFormSubmit as the user who submits it?

Tags: google-apps-script

When I create a Trigger the script runs as my user. This is nice because if the script sends an email I will then be able to find that message inside my gmail sent label!

I wish to create a form on my Domain so that this behavior happens for any user within my domain who submits the form.

This would allow me to add **TO** and **CC** fields and the user would be able to fill the form and have the script send a custom message on for him.

**Any ideas?**

**Update:**

Does the following idea make sense?

I know about the [Undestanding Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers) security measures, but...

I was thinking that maybe if the user that will use the form also accesses and authorizes a second script. Then the form submission could access the second script and pass the form values as parameters resulting in the second script sending the email as the user who submitted the form and authorized the second script...

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to run onFormSubmit as the user submitting.
However i dont see why you need that to be able to send emails on form submit. Its unrelated.

Comment: I want the form to perform some actions and send a message. I want the sent message to be authentically sent *from the user who submitted the form*.

Answer (score 0):

[Appscript doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers) states it clearly: the trigger is run under the identity who installed the trigger. No workaround